# Is there an English version of the book 'Festkörperphysik' by Rudolf Gross and Achim Marx?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, specific-reference

I heard this book is very very nice, but too bad I cannot read German...yet..And I heard last year they published an English version, but I cannot find it anywhere.

If anyone knows about it, it will be huge help!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is based on the lectures on condensed matter physics held by Prof. Gross at Munich University of Technology. Unfortunately, the book has yet to be translated into English. [The university website](https://www.wmi.badw.de/teaching/Lecturenotes/index.html) does give some information on the lecture.

The chapter on additional literature in the book lists a couple of English textbooks on the subject as well:

- Solid State Physics, Harald Ibach, Hans Lüth, 2. Auflage, Springer
  Verlag, Berlin (1995)
- Fundamentals of the Theory of Metals, A. A.
  Abrikosov, North-Holland, Amsterdam (1988)
- Quantum Theory of the Solid State, J. Callaway, Academic Press, New York (1991)
- Advanced Solid State Physics, Philip Phillips, Cambridge University Press,
  (2012) Principles of the Theory of Solids, J. M. Ziman, Cambridge
  University Press, Cambridge (1972)